# Adding a value from a TextBox to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, string, listview, textbox

I'm kinda new to programming and I'm writing a simple WPF program to find the factors of a given number. How do I add a value from a textbox to the listview for it to find the factors. I'm using the following code:

```
    public List<int> Factor(int number)
    {
        List<int> factors = new List<int>();

        number = Convert.ToInt32(txtFactorThis.Text);

        int max = (int)Math.Sqrt(number);  
        for (int factor = 1; factor <= max; ++factor)
        { 
            if (number % factor == 0)
            {
                factors.Add(factor);
                if (factor != number / factor)
                { 
                    factors.Add(number / factor);
                }
            }
        }

        string stringfactors = string.Join(",", factors.ToArray());
        txtPrimeFactors.Text = stringfactors;
        return factors;

    }
```

and how do you load the list values to another textbox to show the results?

Comment: are you using MVVM pattern?

Comment: umm no, i don't think so.

Comment: try use list.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Content = "headr" }); where list is the name of listview or you can bind the List to the listview

Answer (score 0):

Considering the above mentioned code gets called on some event, you can create a list box in your xaml and then bind that xaml to a property in code behind..

and when you return a list from this method, just set that property before that.

so, have a property like

```
public List<int> FactorsData{get;set;}
```

and then set this property

```
FactorsData = factors;
return factors;
```

in your xaml bind your list box to this FactorsData property

In your xaml add a list box like this.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FactorsData}"/>
```

in your code behind in constructor do this

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

add a FactorsData property to your codeBehind as stated above.

and your method should now do this

```
public List<int> Factor(int number)
{
    List<int> factors = new List<int>();

    number = Convert.ToInt32(txtFactorThis.Text);

    int max = (int)Math.Sqrt(number);  
    for (int factor = 1; factor <= max; ++factor)
    { 
        if (number % factor == 0)
        {
            factors.Add(factor);
            if (factor != number / factor)
            { 
                factors.Add(number / factor);
            }
        }
    }

    string stringfactors = string.Join(",", factors.ToArray());
    txtPrimeFactors.Text = stringfactors;

    this.FactorsData = factors;

    return factors;

}
```

Comment: you will have to set data context of control to this in constructor to have binding working.

Comment: umm about that, how do you call that kind of code on a button click event? sorry for my noobness